# <nav> and <section> elements do not show up

Tags: css, html, nav

Website:

- http://www.crystal-grace.so/compendium/resume.html
- http://www.crystal-grace.so/compendium/index.html

CSS:

- http://www.crystal-grace.so/compendium/css/master.css

Hi, for some reason the nav and section elements do not show on the site. The only attributes are the height and background-color that shows. It shows up properly on my old (3.6.25) version of Firefox, but remains the same with Chrome and Safari.

I believe the master.css needs to be fixed for the nav and section elements, but I am unsure.

FYI, I have put the following in my document:

1) both HTML files

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

2) master.css

```
header, footer, article, section, nav, menu, hgroup {  
display: block;  
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I forgot to mention, the second HTML file is http://www.crystal-grace.so/compendium/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is causing the problem:

```
footer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #1D1C1C;
}
```

Just remove that `background` property... or have this instead:

```
background-color: #1D1C1C;
```

The `0 0` part of the original value appears to overlay the page with the `#1D1C1C` color. That value doesn't make sense to me...

Answer (score 4):

The footer is over the whole thing. If you assign a lower value to the footer's `z-index`, like `-200`, they show up. (tested in Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

I have found something else than others. If you remove `float: left;` from styling of `section` tag (line no. 148. in `master.css` file), both seem to be working correctly.

Personally, I think you have made an overkill with styling, if so many solutions are correct and working.

Comment: I removed the float: left; on my file, and on Firefox, it removes the background color. At least on my version. But, you are right, I think I've done an overkill with styling. I'm still relatively new to this ^_^